# Plotting 3 Variables on One Chart - ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some experience with base R but am trying to learn tidyverse and ggplot. I have a dataframe with 4 columns of data. I want a simple x-y plot, where the first column of data is on the x-axis, and the data in the other 3 columns is plotted on the y-axis, resulting in 3 lines on one plot. The first 15 lines of my data look like this (sorry about the image - I don't know how to insert a sample of my data):

[screen shot - first 15 rows of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Teszb.png)

I tried to plot the second and third columns of data as follows: ,

```
ggplot(data=SWRC_SL, aes(x=SWRC_SL$pressure_head, y=SWRC_SL$UNSODA_theta)) + 
geom_line(colour="red") + scale_x_log10() +
ggplot(data=SWRC_SL, aes(x=SWRC_SL$pressure_head, y=SWRC_SL$Vrugt_theta)) + 
geom_line(colour="blue") + scale_x_log10()
```

I get this error:

> Error: Don't know how to add ggplot(data = SWRC_SL, aes(x = SWRC_SL$pressure_head, y = SWRC_SL$Vrugt_theta)) to a plot

I believe I should be using something like "group=" to indicate which columns should be plotted, but I haven't been able to find an example that shows how you can use gglot to plot data across multiple columns. What am I missing ?

Comment: To provide a good reproducible example, you can check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

`ggplot()` is only ever called once when you create a chart. Try with the following:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=SWRC_SL, aes(x=pressure_head, y=UNSODA_theta), colour="red") + 
  geom_line(data=SWRC_SL, aes(x=pressure_head, y=Vrugt_theta), colour="blue") + 
  scale_x_log10()
```

A better method would be to turn your data to long, where the `UNSODA_theta` and `Vrugt_theta` data are in the same column (say `thetas`), and have another column (say `type_theta`) indicating whether the data is for `UNSODA_theta` or `Vrugt_theta`. Then you could do the following:

```
ggplot(data=SWRC_SL, aes(x=pressure_head, y=thetas, colour=type_theta)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_log10()
```

This is more desirable because ggplot2 will include a legend indicating what type of theta the colours are applied to.

Comment: Converting the data to long is the best way to go, it's what ggplot is designed to expect and it makes a lot of ggplot's features work automatically.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I used the code provided by dc37 and the results are great.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Marius, the most efficient way to plot your data is to convert them into a long format.

Using `tidyverse`, you can have the use of `pivot_longer` function (from `tidyr` package) and write the following code:

```r
library(tidyverse)
SWRC_SL %>% pivot_longer(.,-pressure_head, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = pressure_head, y = value, color = variable))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_log10()
```

**EDIT: Illustrating example**

Using this dummy dataset:

```r
  pressure UNSODA_theta Vrugt_theta Cassel_theta
1        0   -1.4672500   1.4119747   -2.0553118
2        1    0.5210227   0.6189239    1.4817574
3        2   -0.1587546   1.4094018    2.2796175
4        3    1.4645873   2.6888733   -0.4631109
5        4   -0.7660820   2.5865884   -1.8799346
6        5   -0.4302118   0.6690922    0.9633620
```

First, you pivot your data into a long format:

```r
df %>% pivot_longer(.,-pressure, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value")

# A tibble: 45 x 3
   pressure variable      value
      <int> <chr>         <dbl>
 1        0 UNSODA_theta -1.47 
 2        0 Vrugt_theta   1.41 
 3        0 Cassel_theta -2.06 
 4        1 UNSODA_theta  0.521
 5        1 Vrugt_theta   0.619
 6        1 Cassel_theta  1.48 
 7        2 UNSODA_theta -0.159
 8        2 Vrugt_theta   1.41 
 9        2 Cassel_theta  2.28 
10        3 UNSODA_theta  1.46 
# … with 35 more rows
```

Now, your data are suitable for the plotting with `ggplot2`, you can directly add `ggplot` command to the previous command by adding a "pipe" (`%>%`) between them:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% pivot_longer(.,-pressure, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = pressure, y = value, color = variable))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_log10()
```

And you get the following plot with legend included:
[image]

**Data example**

```r
structure(list(pressure = 0:14, UNSODA_theta = c(-1.46725002909224, 
0.521022742648139, -0.158754604716016, 1.4645873119698, -0.766081999604665, 
-0.430211753928547, -0.926109497377437, -0.17710396143654, 0.402011779486338, 
-0.731748173119606, 0.830373167981674, -1.20808278630446, -1.04798441280774, 
1.44115770684428, -1.01584746530465), Vrugt_theta = c(1.41197471231751, 
0.61892394889108, 1.40940183965093, 2.68887328620405, 2.58658843344197, 
0.669092199317234, -1.28523553529247, 3.49766158983416, 1.66706616676549, 
1.5413273359637, 0.986600476854091, 1.51010842295293, 0.835624168230333, 
1.42069464325451, 0.599753256022356), Cassel_theta = c(-2.05531181632119, 
1.48175740118232, 2.27961753824932, -0.46311085383842, -1.87993463341154, 
0.963361958516736, -0.0670637053409687, -2.59982761023726, 0.00319778952040447, 
-0.945450500892219, -0.511452869790608, -1.73485854395378, 2.7047128618762, 
-0.496698054586832, -2.40827011837962)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```